# Max absolute difference between elements of two subarrays

Tags: algorithm

Given an array. An integer `K` divides array into two subarrays. The `diffK` is defined as `max({A[0], A[1],....A[K]})- max({A[K+1],A[K+2],...A[n-1]})`. Return maximum absolute value of `diifK`. Time Complexity has to be `O(n)` and max space `complexity O(n)`

Comment: Don't forget to include what you've tried so far ...

Comment: Couldn't think of a algo in O(n). O(n2) has obvious solution

Comment: Is this literally a "do my homework" question?

Answer (score 4):

It's straightforward to build, in a single pass forward through the array, a "helper" array that tracks the maximum value seen up through a given index. (So, for any given `K`, `helper[K] = max({A[0], A[1],....A[K]})`.)

Then, in a single pass *backward* through the array, you can track the maximum value seen from a given index onward (`max({A[K+1],A[K+2],...A[n-1]})`, where `K` is the index), and compare it to the value of the above "helper" array at that index. Keep track of the largest difference you ever see between the two values at the same index, and return the result.